# Css drop-down sub-menu not waiting for mouse

Tags: css, submenu

**Problem**: Why when i go with the mouse over "About" the sub-menu appears but if i try to go into any of it items it disappears?

Part of my style.css:

```
#menu {
    padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
    position: relative;
    background: #209D9D url(images/img02.gif) repeat-x top left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 890px;
    border-top: solid 1px #5AD7D7;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #007D7D;
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

#menu a:hover{
    color: #136F6F;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li.first {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
}

#menu ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#menu ul ul li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

#menu ul ul li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;  
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #209D9D;
    color: white;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 75px auto 0 auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Part of my index.html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="first current_page_item"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Papers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Curriculum Vitae</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li> -->
            </ul>
            <br class="clearfix" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Your `li` item is `inline`, try setting it to `block` (float it left to make the nav vertical)

Answer (score 0):

Change padding of `#menu ul li` to `padding: 20px;`

Play around the values.

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/8kqtJ/)

**EDIT**

Instead of changing the `li`'s padding, I had added below css:

```
#menu ul li a {
    padding:20px 0;
}
#menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 0;
}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/8kqtJ/1/)

Try it.

Comment: Updated my answer with another solution. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gap between your menu and submenu, when your cursor goes over this gap, the submenu disappears, try changing "top: 35px;" in "#menu ul ul" to "top: 20px;"

Comment: Hmm. Works fine for me on FF and Chrome. What browser/version are you using?